# R - Shift specified columns using minimum value into positive values

Tags: r

I'm looking for an easy way to add the minimum value for each column inside my dataframe.

This feels like a common thing, but I haven't been able to find any good answers yet...maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Let's say I've got two columns (in reality I have close to 100) with positive and negative numbers.

```
w <- c(9, 9, 9, 9)
x <- c(-2, 0, 1, 3)
y <- c(-1, 1, 3, 4)

z <- as.data.frame(cbind(w, x, y))

  w  x  y
1 9 -2 -1
2 9  0  1
3 9  1  3
4 9  3  4
```

I want `z` to look like this after a transformation for only x and y columns [,2:3]

```
  w  x  y
1 9  0  0
2 9  2  2
3 9  3  4
4 9  5  5
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

dplyr::mutate(z, across(c(x, y), ~ . + abs(min(.))))

  w x y
1 9 0 0
2 9 2 2
3 9 3 4
4 9 5 5
```

You can also do by column position rather than column name by changing `c(x,y)` to `2:3` or `c(2:3, 5)` for non-sequential column positions.

Comment: How would I declare the specific columns? I updated my example above.

Comment: Then I would use `mutate` and `across` from the `dplyr` package. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hrm, I really like the tidyr approach and this format, but I'm getting all my declared fields coming up as `NA`

Comment: `adstrat <- mutate(adstrat, across(c(33:137), ~ . + abs(min(.))))` is my application of that snippet (my df is called `adstrat` and `33:137` are the columns of interest)

Comment: Are there `NA` in your columns? If so change to `min(., na.rm = T)`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends exactly what you mean and what you want to happen if there aren't negative values. No matter the values, this will anchor the minimum at 0, but you should be able to adapt it if you want something slightly different.

```
z[] = lapply(z, function(col) col - min(col))
z
#   x y
# 1 0 0
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 4
# 4 5 5
```

As a side note, `as.data.frame(cbind(x, y))` is bad - if you have a mix of numeric and character values, `cbind()` will convert everything to character. It's shorter and better to simplify to `data.frame(x, y)`.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do there, but how would I declare this for specific columns?

(Yeah, the cbind was just my shorthand to generate the example.)

Comment: If you have a vector of columns you want to apply this to, say `my_cols = c("col1", "col3", "col4")` - also could be a logical vector, then you can specify those columns: `z[my_cols] = lapply(z[my_cols], ...)`

Comment: And yes, I understand the `cbind` isn't material to the question, it's just a bad habit I see a lot and I try to point it out when I see it to help people form better habits.

Comment: `my_col <- c(33:137)`

`adstrat[my_col] <- lapply(adstrat, function(my_col) my_col - min(my_col))` isn't working on my end.

Comment: You need to subset `adstrat` when you pass it to `lapply`: `my_col <- c(33:137); adstrat[my_col] <- lapply(adstrat[my_col], function(col) col - min(col))`. Use different names for the function argument and the vector of columns you want transform to keep things a little less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want

```
z[] <- lapply(z, function(columnValues) columnValues + abs(min(columnValues)))
```